# asp.net web config <appSettings file="">

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have a web solution which has mutiple projects, One of those projects is used to hold different config files for different environments eg dev.config, staging.config, production.config

Id like to know if it is possible to use the web config  tag to reference one on these config files , the problem is that because the files are in a separate project, there is an issue accessing them, ive tried using relative path but to no avail, any ideas please?

Answer (score 1):

**Updated**:
You should be able to solve your problems with this article:
[Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET 2.0 Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/kb/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx#appendixb)

**Old:**
[Include Multiple .Config Files in ASP.NET Web Application](http://www.beansoftware.com/asp.net-tutorials/multiple-config.aspx)

Comment: that does not answer my question of referencing the config file in a separate class project

Answer (score 0):

You can use specific config file in the web.config.



MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228154.aspx

Comment: this url is no longer available in october 2012